# Capture bash command output in multiple, independent processes without repetition or use of tmp files

Tags: bash

To capture the output of a bash process, we can use redirects or pipes:

```sh
fooProcess > output.txt
```

...or...

```sh
fooProcess | barProcess
```

I'm curious if there is a way to capture the output of `fooProcess` and re-use it? For example, here's the repetitive approach:

```sh
fooProcess | barProcess
fooProcess | bifProcess
```

...or...

```sh
fooProcess > file1.txt
fooProcess > file2.txt
```

In bash, what's the way to do two independent things with the output of `fooProcess` without repeating it or storing it some way? Something like:

"Execute `fooProcess` once and then store all its output in both file1.txt AND file2.txt" or
"Execute `fooProcess` once and then pipe it first to `barProcess` and then to `bifProcess`".

Does bash even do this? What's the term for it?

Comment: bash has process substitution which you can use with `tee`, but I'm not sure if that's what you're asking for

Comment: Yeah, `tee` is the thing - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write to multiple files, use [`tee`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html):

```
cmd | tee file1 file2
```

To pipe to multiple processes, you can use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) and `tee`:

```
cmd | tee >(process1) >(process2)
```

These both still print to standard output. If you don't want that, you have to redirect one more time:

```
cmd | tee file1 file2 >/dev/null
cmd | tee >(process1) >(process2) >/dev/null
```

or use redirect to one of the files/processes like this:

```
cmd | tee file1 > file2
cmd | tee >(process1) | process2
```